# expl3 replace \tex_lowercase:D for colon parsing

Tags: expl3

I am a newbie to expl3 programming and stumbled over a problem with colon (`:`) parsing.

For some TikZ related code I have to split `#1:#2` into pieces. I found several questions and in this direction, but I could not manage to find a proper solution.

I was able to reproduce the *lower case trick*, but this includes the deprecated `\tex_lowercase:D`. Here is my current working, but deprecated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_nopar:Npn \__example_point:nn #1#2
  {
    Example~with~#1~and~#2.
  }


\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `? } { `: }
\tex_lowercase:D {
  \group_end:
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \__example_point:w #1 ? #2 \q_stop
}{
    \__example_point:nn {#1}{#2}
  }


\cs_set_nopar:Npn \__example_point:n #1
  {
    \__example_point:w #1 \q_stop
  }


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myexample}{ m }{ \__example_point:n {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\myexample{34.2:47.9}

\end{document}
```

The output is

> Example with 34.2 and 47.9.

I am searching for a replacement for `\tex_lowercase:D` and my current `\__example_point:w`.

I guess there is some clever way using expansions, but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exploit `\use:x`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__example_point:nn #1#2
  {
    Example~with~#1~and~#2.
  }

\use:x
  {
    \cs_new_nopar:Npn \exp_not:N \__example_point:w ##1 \c_colon_str ##2 \exp_not:N \q_stop
  }
  {
    \__example_point:nn {#1}{#2}
  }

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__example_point:n #1
  {
    \__example_point:w #1 \q_stop
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myexample}{ m }{ \__example_point:n {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\myexample{34.2:47.9}

\end{document}
```

Note `\cs_new…`, which is better practice than `\cs_set…`.

This also works:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__example_point:nn #1#2
  {
    Example~with~#1~and~#2.
  }

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 \c_colon_str ##2 }
\exp_last_unbraced:NNV \cs_new_nopar:Npn \__example_point:w \l_tmpa_tl \q_stop
  {
    \__example_point:nn {#1}{#2}
  }

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__example_point:n #1
  {
    \__example_point:w #1 \q_stop
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myexample}{ m }{ \__example_point:n {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Your first solution is near my own attempts but with the huge distinction that yours is working and mine not ;-) I just tested it with my real code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Why is `\cs_new...` better than `\cs_set...`? From the description in `interface3.pdf` I had the impression that `new` is always global while `set` is local to TeX groups (?).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Why would you define those helper functions locally? `\cs_set…` is for functions with no “predetermined action” and which may locally change.

Comment: I think from (good|bad) habit. `\newcommand` is local, `\def` is local. Over the years it cut in that using `\global\def` is something you do, if you *really* want it to be global. But, this mindset maybe wrong or outdated.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `\seq_set_split:Nnn` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\cs_set_nopar:Npn \__example_point:nn #1#2
  {
    Example~with~#1~and~#2.
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn}

\cs_set_nopar:Npn \__example_point:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l_tmpa_seq \c_colon_str {#1}
    \__example_point:nn {\seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq {1}}{\seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq {2}}
  }


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myexample}{ m }{ \__example_point:n {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\myexample{34.2:47.9}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\seq_set_split:NVn \l_tmpa_seq \c_colon_str { #1 }` seems better to me

Comment: @egreg yes, good point. I edited.

Comment: I decided to accept @egreg' s answer because of the impression that runtime maybe faster (?). In my application, the macro may be called very often. Anyway, your answer is also very helpful to me, because I am at the very start of learning expl3 and I am sure that I will need sequence splitting soon.

Comment: yes, @egreg's answer is certainly better for low-level code used often.